# How to include where clause in a set query

Tags: mysql

I have the query below and it works exactly as I want EXCEPT I need to be able to include a where clause with the declared variable of startDate and endDate. I keep getting an error on the variables.

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `reportNameTest`//

-- Creates new procedure

CREATE PROCEDURE reportNameTest (
        IN logId varchar (50),
        IN fromDate varchar (50),
        IN toDate varchar (50)
        )

    BEGIN
            DECLARE logInS varchar (50);
            DECLARE startDate varchar (50);
            DECLARE endDate varchar (50);


           SET startDate = FROM_UNIXTIME(fromDate/1000);
           SET endDate = FROM_UNIXTIME(toDate/1000);


 SET @tbl = CONCAT('log',logId);
 SET @s = CONCAT(             
 'SELECT g.groupId,g.name AS groupName,l.logId,l.name AS logName,
       lr.userId,completed, 
      g1.parentId AS parentId1, g1.name AS group1Name,g2.parentId AS parentId2, g2.name AS group2Name,
      g3.parentId AS parentId3, g3.name AS group3Name,u.name,u.userId,lr.*
  FROM logs l
      INNER JOIN activities a ON l.logid = a.logid
      INNER JOIN groups g ON g.groupId = l.groupId
      LEFT JOIN groups g1 ON g.parentId = g1.groupId
      LEFT JOIN groups g2 ON g1.parentId = g2.groupId
      LEFT JOIN groups g3 ON g2.parentId = g3.groupId
      INNER JOIN ' ,@tbl);      

 SET @V = CONCAT (@s,' lr ON lr.activityID = a.activityID
      INNER JOIN users u ON u.userID = lr.userID' );

 SET @W = CONCAT (@V,'WHERE l.completed
        BETWEEN startDate
            AND endDate'); 
  PREPARE stmt FROM @V;

     EXECUTE stmt;
  DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

    END //

DELIMITER ;
```

I am open to any suggestions!
Thank you

Comment: What is the exact error message?

Comment: Is an space missing at the beginning of `SET @W = CONCAT (@V,'WHERE l.completed BETWEEN startDate AND endDate');`? It should be `SET @W = CONCAT (@V,' WHERE l.completed BETWEEN startDate AND endDate');`

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems with your code:

1. You are producing unnecessary variables when building a query string. `@S -> @V -> @W`. But then you prepare your statement from `@V` which doesn't contain the complete query string.
2. Instead of concatenating values of variables `startDate` and `endDate` you put their names in a string literal.
3. Values of `startDate` and `endDate` should be quoted.
4. You don't use `logInS` variable even though you declared it.
5. In your case you need only one variable (unless you do something meaningful with them like validating for example) that will hold a query string.

That being said try it this way

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE reportNameTest(
  IN logId    VARCHAR(50),
  IN fromDate VARCHAR(50),
  IN toDate   VARCHAR(50))
BEGIN
  SET @sql = CONCAT(             
 'SELECT g.groupId, g.name AS groupName, l.logId,l.name AS logName,
      lr.userId,completed, 
      g1.parentId AS parentId1, g1.name AS group1Name,g2.parentId AS parentId2, g2.name AS group2Name,
      g3.parentId AS parentId3, g3.name AS group3Name,u.name,u.userId,lr.*
  FROM logs l
      INNER JOIN activities a ON l.logid = a.logid
      INNER JOIN groups g ON g.groupId = l.groupId
      LEFT JOIN groups g1 ON g.parentId = g1.groupId
      LEFT JOIN groups g2 ON g1.parentId = g2.groupId
      LEFT JOIN groups g3 ON g2.parentId = g3.groupId
      INNER JOIN log', logId, ' lr ON lr.activityID = a.activityID
      INNER JOIN users u ON u.userID = lr.userID
  WHERE l.completed BETWEEN \'', FROM_UNIXTIME(fromDate / 1000), 
  '\' AND \'',  FROM_UNIXTIME(toDate / 1000), '\'');      

  PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
  EXECUTE stmt;
  DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

That should work just fine assuming that you resulting query itself is correct.

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4d100/1)** demo *that outputs the resulting query string instead of executing it*.

Comment: @Portlight Did it help? Do you need more help with your question?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, as @neutrino points out, you're missing a space between `lr.userID` and `WHERE`. To see this you could return the query with `select @W` instead of the prepare and execute. Then try to run that query in a normal mysql commander.

Or you can check the query/general log for the query that fails and find the missing space.

Second, you don't need to build you query in several steps like that, it's probably easier to read if you just do one long change of `concat`.